# How do I use HTML code in Flutter notifications?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I started Flutter exactly today.

I want to use HTML code within Android notifications.

It seems that by setting the DefaultStyleInformation argument to true, HTML can be used, but I don't know how to write the actual code.

//This is the interface provided.

```
/// The default Android notification style.
class DefaultStyleInformation implements StyleInformation {
  /// Constructs an instance of [DefaultStyleInformation].
  const DefaultStyleInformation(
    this.htmlFormatContent,
    this.htmlFormatTitle,
  );

  /// Specifies if formatting should be applied to the content through HTML
  /// markup.
  final bool htmlFormatContent;

  /// Specifies if formatting should be applied to the title through HTML
  /// markup.
  final bool htmlFormatTitle;
}
```

The following is the code I am writing.
I feel I need help with the "//here" part.

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'dart:io'; 

 Future<void> showBigTextNotification() async {
    const styleInformation=DefaultStyleInformation(true,true);
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = 
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
       'channel_id',
       'Channel Name',
       importance: Importance.max,
       priority: Priority.high,
       styleInformation: styleInformation
       ),
       iOS: IOSNotificationDetails());

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id, 
      Platform.isAndroid? '<b>'${title}'</b>': title,     // here???
      Platform.isAndroid? '<b>'${content}'</b>': content, // here???
      payload: 'Destination Screen(Big Text Notification)');
  }

thanks.
```

Comment: PS: The purpose is to display a multi-line string in the notification with a new line

Comment: have you find any solution for this..?

Answer (score 0):

> you problem is in the bigTextInformation style and some more thing are missing please use the below code which will now convert html text into regular text

```
    Future<void> showBigTextNotification() async {
        BigTextStyleInformation bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(
          body, htmlFormatBigText: true,
          htmlFormatTitle:true ,
          htmlFormatContent:true ,
                contentTitle: 'overridden <b>big</b> content title',
                htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
                summaryText: 'summary <i>text</i>',
                htmlFormatSummaryText: true
    
        );
  final androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id',
    'your channel name',
    importance: Importance.max,
    styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
    priority: Priority.high,
    ongoing: true,
    autoCancel: true,
  );
 final iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

   NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =  NotificationDetails(android: androidChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSChannelSpecifics);
    
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          id, 
          Platform.isAndroid? '<b>'${title}'</b>': title,     // here???
          Platform.isAndroid? '<b>'${content}'</b>': content, // here???
          type: platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'Destination Screen(Big Text Notification)');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `BigTextStyleInformation` to show html content in notifications

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  notification.hashCode,
  notification.title,
  '',
  NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      channelDescription: channel.description,
      importance: Importance.high,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
        '<b>Your</b> notification',
        htmlFormatBigText: true,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
);
```